can't catch Unexpected end of stream JedisConnectionException
try (Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource()) {
    logger.info("connection established after attempt: " +attempts);
    return operation.execute(jedis);
}catch (JedisException e) {
             //some code
}

debugger doesnt even stop at catch block or my logs are shown. Why try catch cant catch this?
i dont have any problem with exceptin. I just want to handle it
i want to catch the error

Try cathing with Throwable?

What is the log?


Try cathing with Throwable?
didn't work.
What is the log?
2024-08-28T16:37:24.400+03:00 ERROR 27372 --- [clazz] [pool-8-thread-2] [66cf2804299389ec3088cc28179c58ef-3088cc28179c58ef] redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory         : Error while validating pooled Jedis object.

redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Unexpected end of stream.
at redis.clients.jedis.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:248) ~[jedis-5.1.3.jar:na]
